# Can I unbreak my SharePoint Online admin center page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration

I am performing a tenant-to-tenant SharePoint Online migration. I am migration one site collection at a time and all has gone fine until now. It appears I migrated a site collection over the target SPO Admin Center site. I didn't think that was possible but that's what I get for scripting the process :\

Anyway, the admin center now thinks it is a publishing page, complete with a 'Site Pages' library and a whole mess of other stuff that ought not be there.

[image]

When going to [tenant]-admin.sharepoint.com I am taken to the Welcome Page for the source site collection:
[tenant]-admin.sharepoint.com/SitePages/Home.aspx

If I go directly to the ../_layouts/15/SiteCollections.aspx page, everything is there, so at least no baseline functionality is gone.

I was hoping I could just change the Welcome Page in site settings for the admin center but that was a bust. Any other ideas? I am hoping Microsoft support can just 'undo' this...but I'd rather fix it myself if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a production tenant, and if that were me, I'd open a support ticket. They should be able to reset the welcome page and determine whether any damage has been done.

But if you want to go it alone, try running a `Set-PnPHomePage` after connecting to the admin site via PnP PowerShell. Since the admin pages are all _layouts pages, I'm not sure it'll work. If not you're probably stuck with the support ticket.

At least you'll give those guys something to laugh about over lunch.